# How do I check the previous numbers in the array for a duplicate before placing a new random value in the array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am not allowed to import anything, the requirements state that everything must be already available to you or created by you. I also can't use anything too advanced and have to use loops and if statements to stop the duplicates.

```
int[][] card;
      public BINGOCardEhretEvan(){
         
        card = new int[5][5];
         
         for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < 5; j++){ 
            
             card[i][0] = (int)(Math.random() * 14)+1;
             if (card[i][0] == card[j][0] && i != j)  {card[i][0] = (int)(Math.random() * 14)+1;}
             card[i][1] = (int)(Math.random() * 14)+16;
             if (card[i][1] == card[j][1] && i != j)  {card[i][1] = (int)(Math.random() * 14)+16;}
             card[i][2] = (int)(Math.random() * 14)+31;
             if (card[i][2] == card[j][2] && i != j)  {card[i][2] = (int)(Math.random() * 14)+31;}
             card[i][3] = (int)(Math.random() * 14)+46;
             if (card[i][3] == card[j][3] && i != j)  {card[i][3] = (int)(Math.random() * 14)+46;}
             card[i][4] = (int)(Math.random() * 14)+61;
             if (card[i][4] == card[j][4] && i != j)  {card[i][4] = (int)(Math.random() * 14)+61;}
         }   
            } card[2][2] = 0;
             
     
     
     
      }//end bingoCard class
```

Comment: What is the max limit of the value of the card?

Comment: "_the requirements state that everything must be already available to you_" - Does this mean using standard Java libraries is OK?

Comment: So why can't you just specify the entire package name.  Then you won't be importing anything.  But you don't need to check for duplicates anyway.  Just assign the values in order and shuffle them.  Shuffle routines are easy to write.  Search the web for  Fisher-Yates algorithm.

Comment: @chickengod, I provided an answer that uses a LinkedHashSet, which is a standard Java library. It prevents duplicate insertions and keeps the insertion order. This should be exactly what you need, much simplified.

Comment: @hfontanez thank you for your help but I cannot use linkedHashSet because we haven’t went over it in class. I

Comment: @chickengod in that case, use one of the solutions linked in the closing statement above. But, I will leave this answer here for future people looking for an answer that doesn't have that constraint.

Comment: @WJS I can't use shuffle routines sadly. I have to use loops and if statements

Comment: @Agam the limit is 75. It follows the regular bingo rules which are column B is 1-15 column I is 16-30 column N is 31-45 column G is 46-60 column O is 61-75

Comment: @chickengod this might be a little too late for you, but I updated my answer to include code _STRICTLY_ following your homework requirements.  It is still a much simplified version than your original code and I am performing a simple check for duplicates; giving you an explanation for its time complexity. I did this to help you in your learning process. I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use `java.util.Set` (if allowed) to eliminate the need for checking for duplicates since sets in Java do not allow duplicate values to be inserted. So, a set-based solution will look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[][] card = new Integer[5][5];
    Set<Integer> row = null;

    int seed = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
        row = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        if (i != 0) {
            seed +=15;
        }
        while (row.size() < card[0].length) {
            row.add((int)(Math.random() * 14)+seed);
        }
        card[i] = (Integer[])row.toArray(Integer[]::new);
        System.out.println(row);
    }
}
```

This will result in an output that will look something like this:

```
[1, 4, 14, 8, 2]
[26, 23, 28, 20, 17]
[34, 40, 36, 41, 43]
[46, 48, 58, 49, 51]
[66, 72, 63, 64, 71]
```

The beauty of ***LinkedHashSet*** is that:

1. It ***prevents duplicate values*** to be inserted
2. ***Preserves the insertion order***; acting like an array.

Of course, I assume that duplicate values are only to be prevented in a single row and that a duplicate value could exist in another row. Obviously, if each of the values must be unique, you would need to allow for your randomization function to provide values from 1 up to the number of cells in the grid AND you will generate all the values (in this case 25 values first, and then you will loop thru the set and add the values to each cell after the set is generated.

---

The answer was provided before it was known "card" was for a bingo board. So, I added the code to transpose the grid.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[][] temp = new Integer[5][5];
    Set<Integer> row = null;

    int seed = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        row = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        if (i != 0) {
            seed += 15;
        }
        while (row.size() < temp[0].length) {
            row.add((int) (Math.random() * 14) + seed);
        }
        temp[i] = (Integer[]) row.toArray(Integer[]::new);
        System.out.println(row);
    }

    // transpose the grid to turn it into a bingo board
    int[][] card = new int[5][5];
    for (int col = 0; col < temp.length; col++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < temp.length; r++) {
            card[r][col] = temp[col][r];
        }
    }
        
    System.out.println("\nTransposed:");

    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
    Arrays.stream(card).forEach((i) -> {
        buff.append("[");
        Arrays.stream(i).forEach((j) -> buff.append(j + " "));
        buff.replace(buff.toString().lastIndexOf(" "), buff.length(),  "");
        buff.append("]\n");
    });
        
    System.out.print(buff.toString().replaceAll(" ", ", "));
}
```

Now this program outputs:

```
[10, 8, 9, 13, 14]
[27, 29, 19, 26, 20]
[34, 38, 43, 40, 31]
[52, 49, 59, 53, 50]
[69, 63, 62, 64, 67]

Transposed:
[10, 27, 34, 52, 69]
[8, 29, 38, 49, 63]
[9, 19, 43, 59, 62]
[13, 26, 40, 53, 64]
[14, 20, 31, 50, 67]
```

Now you can clearly see that the values of each original row has been transposed to the corresponding BINGO column, so that values between 1-15 are in the first column (B), 16-30 under the second column (I), 31-45 under the third (N), 46-60 under the fourth (G), and 61-75 under the fifth (O).

---

Here is a solution that complies with the OP requirement posted on the comments ("*I cannot use `LinkedHashSet` because we haven’t went[sic] over it in class*").

```
public class BingoBoard2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int GRID_SIZE = 5;
        int[][] card = new int[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];
        int seed = 1;
        for (int col = 0; col < GRID_SIZE; col++) {
            if (col != 0) {
                seed += 15;
            }
            for (int row = 0; row < GRID_SIZE; row++ ) {
                int value = -1;
                do {
                    value = (int) (Math.random() * 14) + seed;
                } while (valueInArray(card, col, row, value));
                card[row][col] = value;                 
            }
        }

        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
        Arrays.stream(card).forEach((i) -> {
            buff.append("[");
            Arrays.stream(i).forEach((j) -> buff.append(j + " "));
            buff.replace(buff.toString().lastIndexOf(" "), buff.length(),  "");
            buff.append("]\n");
        });
        
        System.out.print(buff.toString().replaceAll(" ", ", "));
    }
    
    private static boolean valueInArray(int[][] arr, int col, int maxIndex, int value) {

        for (int row = 0; row < maxIndex; row++) {
            if (arr[row][col] == value) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This latest solution

1. Doesn't use `Set` or `LinkedHashSet`
2. Doesn't transpose the 2D array
3. Doesn't insert duplicate values into the array.

The check for duplicate simply checks the current column values in the range of index 0 up to the current index. Basically, it checks all previous inserts in the current column. Since the randomizer generates unique values for each column (based on BINGO), there is no need to check for duplicates outside the current column. So, per column, ***there will be approximately 4! checks per column*** (*5 * 4!* per board - or 50 checks if my math is correct).

A sample output for this version:

```
[1, 25, 31, 46, 64]
[4, 22, 36, 49, 66]
[5, 24, 37, 48, 72]
[9, 19, 32, 50, 63]
[2, 23, 38, 54, 71]
```

Number of Duplicate Checks: 55 (I have seen this count range from the low 50's to about low 70's). This is of, course, heavily dependent on the randomizing function with regards to how frequent duplicate numbers are generated in the given range. Given the fact that for each column the range is small (only 15 numbers), the frequency of numbers repeating is high (probably 1 in 3). Since there are 25 values in this grid, this seems to make sense (Dup count being somewhere 2-3 times the size of the grid). Maybe someone better in math than me can provide a better explanation about the probability of numbers repeating.